# CSS3 unexpected behavior CSS is not overrided

Tags: css

i encounter this chunk of code while trying to learn CSS3.
the code below result is: i am awesome written in red.
but when trying the code without the first three lines of the style tag or when adding !important to fifth line of the style tag , the result is: i am awesome written in blue. 
could anyone explain to me this behavior.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <style> 
       #awesome .favorite:not(#awesome) .highlight {
          color: red;
       }
       #awesome .highlight:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(1) {
          color: blue ;
       } 
     </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <ul class="shopping-list" id="awesome">
       <li>
         <span>Milk</span>
       </li>
       <li class="favorite" id="must-buy">
         <span class="highlight">I am awesome</span>
       </li>
     </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Err, if you're trying it "without the first three lines" which I assume refer to the first rule with color: red, then what other rules are there for the browser to apply besides color: blue?

Comment: none but why doesn't the second rule override the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selector:

```
#awesome .favorite:not(#awesome) .highlight
```

has higher specificity than this one:

```
#awesome .highlight:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(1)
```

Off the top of my head, I don't know how `nth-of-type` or `not` declarations affect specificity, but roughly, the first has two classes and the second has only one, so it makes a bit of sense that it would be more specific.

In css, more specific selectors override less specific ones regardless of order, so your text is red.

Of course if you take out the red class, then the blue one is the most specific, so it will "win". By adding `!important`, you're increasing the specificity of the blue one, so it becomes more specific than the red one and it will "win".

Comment: Every pseudo-class except :not() has the same specificity value as a class selector. :not() takes on the specificity of its argument while itself not counting for a pseudo-class.

Comment: what do you mean by take on the specificity of it's argument?

Comment: @user605505: The specificity of :not(#awesome) is the same specificity as #awesome - one id selector.